# trouble in JList asterisk print

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

hello guys i am trying to do some of forloops that i need to build in asterisk but i dont know how to print it into my JList i printed the 3 patterns asterisk loop but i need to print the last one the D radio button will handle the forloop here is my code so far

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LOOPING extends JFrame implements ItemListener,ActionListener
{
    JFrame jeframe = new JFrame("LOOPING");
    JPanel jenel = new JPanel();
    JLabel let = new JLabel("Choose a letter");
    JRadioButton first = new JRadioButton("A");
    JRadioButton second = new JRadioButton("B");
    JRadioButton third = new JRadioButton("C");
    JRadioButton fourth = new JRadioButton("D");
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    JButton but = new JButton("Clear");
    JList asterisk = new JList();
    JLabel je = new JLabel();

    DefaultListModel aslist = new DefaultListModel();

    public LOOPING()
    {
        jenel.setLayout(null);
        jeframe.setVisible(true);
        jeframe.setBounds(330,100,200,440);
        jeframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        let.setBounds(10,10,100,20);
        first.setBounds(20,50,50,30);
        second.setBounds(20,110,50,30);
        third.setBounds(100,50,50,30);
        fourth.setBounds(100,110,50,30);
        asterisk.setBounds(07,150,170,170);
        je.setBounds(07,90,110,170);
        but.setBounds(50,350,80,25);

        jenel.add(let);
        jenel.add(first);
        jenel.add(second);
        jenel.add(third);
        jenel.add(fourth);
        jenel.add(asterisk);
        jenel.add(je);
        jenel.add(but);
        group.add(first);
        group.add(second);
        group.add(third);
        group.add(fourth);

        first.addItemListener(this);
        second.addItemListener(this);
        third.addItemListener(this);
        fourth.addItemListener(this);
        but.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(jenel);
        jeframe.add(jenel);
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        ItemSelectable beu;
        beu = e.getItemSelectable();
        String s = "*";

        if(beu == first)
        {
            for(int a=0; a<=4; a++)
            {
                for(int b=1; b<a; b++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                je.setText(je.getText() + s);
                aslist.addElement(je.getText());
                asterisk.setModel(aslist);
            }       
        }

        if (beu == second) 
        {
            for (int v = 1; v <= 5; v++)
            {
                String stars = "";

                for (int j = v; j <= 5; j++)
                {
                    stars += s;
                }

                je.setText(stars);
                System.out.println();
                aslist.addElement(je.getText());
                asterisk.setModel(aslist);
            }
        }

        if (beu == third)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m <5; m++)
            {
                String stars = "";

                for (int k = 5; k > m; k--)
                {
                    stars += " ";   
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) 
                {
                    stars += "*";       
                }

                je.setText(stars);
                aslist.addElement(je.getText());
                asterisk.setModel(aslist);

            }
        }

        if(beu == fourth)
        {

        }    
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    { 
        if(e.getSource() == but)
        {
            group.clearSelection();
            aslist.removeAllElements();
            je.setText(""); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        LOOPING lup = new LOOPING();
    }
}
```

i am trying to build in my D button the button D will output this asterisk pattern using forloop

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

this is my code for D radiobutton i need it to be above asterisk

```
if(beu == fourth)
{
    for(int v= 1; v<=5; v++)
    {
        String ss= "";

        for(int c=6; c>v; c--)    
            ss +="*";

        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();

        for(int c=0; c<v; c++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        je.setText(ss);
        aslist.addElement(je.getText());
        asterisk.setModel(aslist);
    }                                    
}
```

Comment: Please help us help you by fixing the formatting of your code.

Comment: sir i have a trouble of printing the asterisk form in my D button .

Comment: You should stop removing the body of your questions, like you did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22092196/2587435) also. This Q&A format is not just for you the poster, but everyone else that comes along with the same problem. By you removing all your content, you 1) may invalidate an answer 2) don't allow readers to see mistakes you have made and maybe compare to theirs. I'm going to roll this back, and same with the other one. If you didn't want your whole program posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out.

```
   if (beu == fourth) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String stars = "";

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                stars += " ";
            }
            for (int k = 5; k > i; k--) {
                stars += "*";
            }

            je.setText(stars);
            aslist.addElement(je.getText());
            asterisk.setModel(aslist);
        }
    }
```

Output

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```